# How to round number in actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

how can I round number to up down or to the 0.5 using action script 3.0
for example

- 4.9 will be rounded to 5
- 4.7 will be rounded to 4.5
- 2.4 will be rounded to 2.5
- 2.3 will be rounded to 2

thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
Math.round(2 * number_here) / 2
```

Comment: doest it round to the 0.5 if needed ?

Comment: My answer has been updated to reflect your needs. It rounds to 0.5 where needed.

Comment: ok, thank you, and i put effort back to the community, sooryy

Answer (score 0):

```
z = Math.floor(n);
p = n-z;

if(p<0.25)
    ans=z;
else if(p>0.75)
    ans=z+1;
else
    ans=z+0.5;
```