# How can I remove the decimals without rounding the number in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, decimal

Usually, I would use toFixed to get less decimals, but this time I need the number to not be rounded.
Example: 3.99 -> 3
How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round number in actionscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889312/how-to-round-number-in-actionscript)

Comment: It's a little bit different.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `int` :

```
trace(int(3.99))           // gives : 3
```

Or `Math.floor` :

```
trace(Math.floor(3.99))    // gives : 3
```

Comment: Also, should you want the number to be truncated to a certain decimal place, you can use `Math.floor(number*10)/10`, with possible `toFixed()` wrap to avoid nasty 0.000000001's.